# Error with Android gradle task :app:preDexDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Having an issue with a project that has trouble with the :app:preDexDebug task when trying to run app. Error received is:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Current settings:

```
Android Studio 0.8.1
Android Build Tools 20.0.0
Java 1.7_55
Windows 7
```

Even a default project does not run, although a gradle sync builds fine.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\dx.bat --dex --output C:\...\TestApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-c0d17b20b65717b1b327ef7ea8fea7e8a443e7fe.jar C:\...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\19.1.0\support-v4-19.1.0.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Try build tools 19.1.0

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work...

Comment: Tried stuff on my macbook and all was fine. I'll chock this up to a corrupt windows file somewhere. trying a complete re-install of Studio, SDK tools, etc..

Comment: Finally got it working. Complete re-install of Android stuff, studio, multiple reboots, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved (on windows) by setting

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Now script reports

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   and works correctly.

What is strange, setting up variables GRADLE_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS had no effect.